# Mock of DbSet AddOrUpdate fails to update my object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I have this unit test. It tests the `UpdateEmployee` method for my `IEmployeeService`.

```
    private readonly IEmployeeService _employeeService;

    public EmployeeServiceTests()
    {
        var mockData = new List<Employee>
        {
            new Employee { Id = 0, FirstName = "Homer", LastName = "Simpson" },
            new Employee { Id = 1, FirstName = "Carl", LastName = "Carlson" },
            new Employee { Id = 2, FirstName = "Lenny", LastName = "Leonard" },
        };

        _employeeService = MockSetup.SetupEmployeeService(mockData);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void UpdateEmployee_EmployeeExists_EmployeeGetsUpdated()
    {
        var homer = _employeeService.GetEmployee(0);
        homer.FirstName = "Homer Jay";

        _employeeService.UpdateEmployee(homer);

        var actual = homer.FirstName;
        var expected = _employeeService.GetEmployee(0).FirstName;

        Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    }
```

This is my `UpdateEmployee()` code:

```
    public void UpdateEmployee(EmployeeDto employee)
    {
        var existingEmployee = _dbContext.Employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == employee.Id);

        if (existingEmployee != null)
        {
            _dbContext.Employees.AddOrUpdate(employee.ToEntity());
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Employee does not exist");
        }
    }
```

This is what my mock setup looks like. I use a custom method for mocking `AddOrUpdate`:

```
    public static Mock<MockDbSet<Employee>> CreateEmployeeMockSet(List<Employee> data)
    {
        var mockSet = new Mock<MockDbSet<Employee>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Employee>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.AsQueryable().Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Employee>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.AsQueryable().Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Employee>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.AsQueryable().ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Employee>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.AsQueryable().GetEnumerator());
        mockSet.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<Employee>())).Callback<Employee>(e => data.Add(e));
        mockSet.Setup(d => d.AddOrUpdate(It.IsAny<Employee>())).Callback<Employee>(e => UpdateList(e, data));
        mockSet.Setup(d => d.Remove(It.IsAny<Employee>())).Callback<Employee>(e => data.Remove(e));

        return mockSet;
    }

    private static void UpdateList(Employee employee, List<Employee> data)
    {
        var index = data.FindIndex(e => e.Id == employee.Id);

        data[index] = employee;
    }
```

Unfortunately the update does not work. I get this error:

```
Message: Assert.Equal() Failure
               ↓ (pos 5)
Expected: Homer
Actual:   Homer Jay
               ↑ (pos 5)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where is your `UpdateEmployee` method in the code?

Comment: @TanvirArjel I edited into the question, sorry about that

Comment: Is this is an ASP.NET Core project?

Comment: @TanvirArjel It's .net framework 4.6.1

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a case where you are testing your mock, which is going too deep. The mock is the boundary. It should assert the interaction with the mocked service, not substitute it.

Firstly a warning sign: AddOrUpdate is intended for data migrations, not production code. You can introduce side-effects if you ever pass it an incomplete entity. (erasing data)

For example, if I were mocking out a DbSet or Repository I would look to:

- Mock out the DbSet/Repo that it returns me a known state for my test scenario. (an employee, nothing, exception)
- Assert did SaveChanges get called or not? (yes when I got an employee back, no if there was no employee returned or exception scenario during get, did my service call SaveChanges appropriately?)
- Assert the behaviour if SaveChanges throws an exception. (What should my service do?)

Getting an object from a mock, then testing whether that mock recorded the update is testing the mock, not the service code that should be under test.

Comment: Thank you for the information. One question: you said I shouldn't use AddOrUpdate in production. What should I use then?

Comment: Your application should track whether you are dealing with a new entity scenario or updating an existing one and handle these scenarios separately. In the case of an update it should also consider a row version (timestamp etc.) to detect changes on stale data. (data updated by another user/process since the 'read' was taken for this update)  Re: the risks of AddOrUpdate: https://www.michaelgmccarthy.com/2016/08/24/entity-framework-addorupdate-is-a-destructive-operation/